# Show View Returning Error: undefined method `each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I researched this topic here on Stack Overflow but I still can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My show.html view file is throwing this error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Advertisement:0x007fce42676a70>
```

when I'm clicking on my individual ads within my browser locally.

**My show.html view code:**

```
<h1><%= @advertisement.title %></h1>

<%= link_to "Edit advertisement", edit_advertisement_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Delete advertisement", @advertisement, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this advertisement?' } %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p class="lead"><%= @advertisement.copy %></p>
    <% @advertisement.each do |advertisement| %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= link_to advertisement.title, advertisement_path(@advertisement) %>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= link_to "New Advertisement", new_advertisement_path(@advertisement), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My advertisement controller code:**

```
class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @advertisements = Advertisement.all
    # render('advertisements/index.html.erb')
  end

  def show
    # raise 'this is the show action'
    @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
    # render 'advertisements/index.html.erb'
  end

  def edit
    @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @advertisement = Advertisement.new
  end

  def create
    @advertisement = Advertisement.new
    @advertisement.title = params[:advertisement][:title]
    @advertisement.copy = params[:advertisement][:copy]
    @advertisement.price = params[:advertisement][:price]

    if @advertisement.save
      flash[:notice] = "Advertisement was saved."
      redirect_to @advertisement
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the advertisement. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @advertisment = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
    @advertisment.title = params[:advertisement][:title]
    @advertisment.copy = params[:advertisement][:copy]
    @advertisment.price = params[:advertisement][:price]

    if @advertisement.save
      flash[:notice] = "Advertisement was updated."
      redirect_to @advertisement
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error saving advertisement. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

From researching it, I believe my issue is that the `advertisement` object has to be an array. What do I need to change to get the show view to work properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem and explanation:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Advertisement:0x007fce42676a70>
```

The error message gives you the hint. You can call `.each` on a collection type object such as an array or ActiveRecordRelation type objects. In this case, you can't (and should not) call `.each` because there is nothing to loop through or iterate through. You have only one single object here:

```
@advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
```

For your index view, you have the following in your corresponding controller action:

```
@advertisements = Advertisement.all
```

which gives you a collection of `Advertisement` objects. In that case, you can do: `@advertisements.each do ....` in your view.

But, for the `show` action, `@advertisement` is a single object of `Advertisement` class. So, you should not or can't try to loop thrugh that. You just need to show the corresponding attributes/column values for that `@advertisement` object in your `show` view.

#### Solution:

So, change your `show.html.erb` to this (without using `.each`) and this should fix your problem:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p class="lead"><%= @advertisement.copy %></p>
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">
              <%= link_to @advertisement.title, advertisement_path(@advertisement) %>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= link_to "New Advertisement", new_advertisement_path(@advertisement), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why I was attempting to loop through on a show view when there is only one advertisement being shown. Makes sense after reading through your response. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `show` view:

```
<h1><%= @advertisement.title %></h1>

<%= link_to "Edit advertisement", edit_advertisement_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Delete advertisement", @advertisement, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this advertisement?' } %>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p class="lead"><%= @advertisement.copy %></p>

    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= link_to @advertisement.title, advertisement_path(@advertisement) %>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <%= link_to "New Advertisement", new_advertisement_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying all advertisements you should you index method and for displaying a specific advertisement you can use show method like :-

```
# Advertisement controller
def index
    @advertisements = Advertisement.all
end

def show
    @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <% @advertisements.each do |advertisement| %>
            <p class="lead"><%= advertisement.copy %></p>
            <div class="media">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        <%= link_to advertisement.title, advertisement_path(advertisement) %>
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <%= link_to "Edit advertisement", edit_advertisement_path(advertisement), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<%= link_to "Delete advertisement", advertisement, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this advertisement?' } %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= link_to "New Advertisement", new_advertisement_path, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="lead"><%= @advertisement.copy %></p>
        <p class="lead"><%= @advertisement.title %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```